# Connecting keywords with location

Tags: seo, google-analytics, keywords

***Is there a way to connect the keyword with the location withing Google Analytics?***

I would like to be able to see what cities are searching for what terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "new" Google analytics (I put new in quote marks because one day the new version will be the old version, but in August 2011 it's new) on the report of keywords you can click "secondary dimension" and choose Visitors -> City.

On the old version, on the keyword report you click the dropdown arrow next to None above the list and then choose Geographic -> City.

Comment: Excellent, but is there a way to make this a widget? I use the dashboard way more than the main section.

Comment: I'm trying to do this - connect the keywords (clicks) with the geo location (country). How to do this now? Please help.